# Fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value (lldb)

Tags: ios, swift

```
override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject!) {
    if segue.identifier == "showLocalMenuDetail" {
        if let indexPath = self.tableView.indexPathForSelectedRow() {
            self.slideMenuController()?.closeLeft()
            let destinationController = segue.destinationViewController as DetailViewController
            destinationController.localMenuImage = self.locals[indexPath.row].image
            destinationController.localMenuTitle = self.locals[indexPath.row].title

    } }
}
```

I got the error at this "self.tableView.indexPathForSelectedRow()".I am navigating to other view controller using slide out navigation panel like facebook using segue and embeded navigation controller on left menu.

I don't know what is wrong with it,Please help!

Comment: can you identify where exactly it crashes? From the code it must be self.slideMenuController()?.closeLeft() - that means the optional slideMenuController doesn't exist

Comment: i am using this lib https://github.com/dekatotoro/SlideMenuControllerSwift ,and i add table cell to my left slide menu.When i click one of them,that error appear.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Such errors occur when you attempt to access the value of a variable declared as an 'Implicitly Unwrapped Optional' (that is, declared with a `!`) but when that variable is unbound (bound to `nil`).

In your case, the crash occurs because in a `UITableViewController` the `tableView` property is defined as:

```
var tableView: UITableView!
```

It is an implicitly unwrapped optional.  If it is unbound, crash.

You've not bound `tableView` within Xcode's Interface Builder to your `UITableViewController`.  In Xcode, if you look at your controller in the 'Connections Inspector' you will find under 'Outlets' that 'view' is not bound.  Thus, the expression `self.tableView` will produce a runtime crash.