# How do I fix this crash? Xcode 6 Swift

Tags: xcode, swift, webview, crash, mfmailcomposer

I am only coding in two features. MailComposer and WebView. But when I run my app and go to the email interface tab it crashes "fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value (lldb)". When I go to the tab that displays the webview, it works fine. The Webview.loadRequest(request) is messing something up with the mail coding. But I don't know where I can put it to make both features work.

If anyone has any clue how to fix this, please let me know. Thanks.

Here is the coding for the View.Controller.Swift file...

```
import UIKit
import MessageUI


    class ViewController: UIViewController, MFMailComposeViewControllerDelegate {

        @IBOutlet weak var Webview: UIWebView!


        @IBOutlet weak var Subject: UITextField!

        @IBOutlet weak var Body: UITextView!




         var URLPath = "http://google.com"

        override func viewDidLoad() {
            super.viewDidLoad()
            // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
            loadAddressURL()


        }


        override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
            super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
            // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
        }




        @IBAction func SendEmail(sender: AnyObject) {

            var SubjectText = "Inquiry:"
            SubjectText += Subject.text

            var MessageBody = Body

            var toRecipients = ["phillip.lebsack1@gmail.com"]

            var mc: MFMailComposeViewController = MFMailComposeViewController()
            mc.mailComposeDelegate = self
            mc.setSubject(SubjectText)
            mc.setMessageBody(MessageBody.text, isHTML: false)
            mc.setToRecipients(toRecipients)

            self.presentViewController(mc, animated: true, completion: nil)


        }


        func mailComposeController(controller: MFMailComposeViewController!, didFinishWithResult result: MFMailComposeResult, error: NSError!) {
            switch result.value{


            case MFMailComposeResultCancelled.value:
                NSLog("Mail Cancelled")
            case MFMailComposeResultSaved.value:
                NSLog("Mail Saved")
            case MFMailComposeResultSent.value:
                NSLog("Mail Sent")
            case MFMailComposeResultFailed.value:
                NSLog("Mail Sent Failure: %@",[error.localizedDescription])
            default:
                break
            }

            self.dismissViewControllerAnimated(true, completion: nil)



        }
        func loadAddressURL(){

            let requestURL = NSURL(string:URLPath)
            let request = NSURLRequest(URL: requestURL!)
            Webview.loadRequest(request)

        }
    }
```

Comment: There are *numerous* questions/answers on this.  The problem is that your `!` variables are not bound in Interface Builder and thus when they are first accessed the `!` causes the (expected) crash.  (see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27981488/fatal-error-unexpectedly-found-nil-while-unwrapping-an-optional-value-lldb)

Comment: How do you bind them in the interface builder?

Comment: @PhillipLebsack Make sure that your `!` variables are `!= nil` before doing anything with them

Comment: Thank you... can you make a tutorial on how to do that?

Comment: In Xcode, control-drag a UI element onto its `@IBOutlet`.  Set up Xcode with 'Show the Assistant Editor' so you have the IB pane next to the source code pane.  (There are other ways; an Xcode UI tutorial will have it).  When the `@IBOutlet` is bound where will be a filled circle next to the `@IBOutlet` in the source code.

Comment: I connected them properly and the filled circles are displayed next to them. It still crashes though.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure no warning message and bind all `@IBOutlet` in your `ViewController`.

[image]

Comment: So how do I actually fix it? I've tried everything I can think of. The crash is saying it's the Webview.loadRequest(request) that's causing it. But it's bound to the UIWebView. So why does it crash when I try to go to the mail interface?